# Obj->Bin in C#?

Tags: .net

I am wondering if there is anything that can quickly convert my class into a `byte[]`. For example if i have `class Foo { public string name; public int age }` I don't want to use reflection but still have a serialize without handwriting one.

The closest thing I know is dapper.net which generates IL code on the fly (after using reflection) and caches the IL/jit code so its pretty much full speed. It would be nice if i have an option to use a light/quick optional compressor for the string but not required. I may also want to throw `Foo[]` (or `List<Foo>`) at this thing. What are my options?

Comment: Do you want to serialize an instance of the class, or do you want to compile the class and save the binary?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'll be using it with redis. I don't know what you mean by 'save the binary' but i'll de/serialize the class often and don't want to reflect (i use a lib with reflection and its painfully slow)

Comment: _sigh_ you mean that you want to serialize _instances_ of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: In any case, try using the DataContractSerializer with a binary XML output. This can be very fast.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: yes. But I still have no idea what it means to 'save the binary' of a class.

Comment: You might have been asking how to compile the class and save the resultant binary code. It could be done, I would just wonder why?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Now I'm thinking about assembly which calls the C# version of `new` and the class constructor... Is that what you were thinking? and no thats... just weird (i know i have a rep for asking stranger questions lol)

Comment: No, I thought you wanted to do what the compiler does. I didn't think you would say "class" but really mean "instance", so I took you at your word. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

Most anything that does serialization is going to use reflection. That doesn't mean it will be slow... often times it will cache the results of the initial calls to the reflection API. However, if (and only if) actual performance testing shows that the BinaryFormatter is not good enough for you, you might also try [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Comment: Nice --> allow pre-generation of a serialization assembly, to remove all reflection at runtime. <-- do you happen to know how to precompile? i cant quiet find it yet. i'm still looking

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Just serialize into a MemoryStream and then get the bytes.

You will have to sprinkle `[Serializable]` on the classes.

As an extension it would look like:

```
public byte[] ToByteArray(this object o)
{
    using (var s = new MemoryStream())
    {
       new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(s, o);
       return s.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something that doesn't use runtime reflection. Something that will be very fast